# Print of gridview is not center align

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview .I provided print option on my page.
Gridview data is center align but when I print header remains center align but data is left align in print preview and print document.
Anybody have idea to configure this print for center align

Comment: Pls provide your aspx markup and code behind so we can better understand your issue.

Comment: @woodykiddy Which code you want.Gridview or print code?